# Total number of intersections within a given radius

Tags: postgis

My dataset is like:

```
row_id,    imei,    points_geom (SRID 4326),   timestamp
```

*Please note imei is the device id.*

Here is what I am trying to do - **For each cluster centroid, I have to check how many track intersections (of different device_id's) occurred within a 500m radius.** An intersection is said to occur if tracks are within 5m of each other.

Here is my code so far:

```
clustering as(
SELECT row_id,imei, points_geom ,time_created, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(points_geom,5243),eps := 10, minPoints := 100) 
  OVER(ORDER BY row_id) AS cluster_id FROM dataset 
)

,

tracks AS
(SELECT 
    imei,
    ST_MakeLine(points_geom ORDER BY time_created) AS track from 
    dataset  
    GROUP BY imei
)

,
cluster_centroids_details as (
SELECT cluster_id, st_centroid(st_union(points_geom)) as cluster_centroid
FROM clustering 
where cluster_id is not null 
GROUP by cluster_id
)
```

**CODE UPDATE 1:** I have **added** the following code:

```
,
intersections as (
SELECT
    ST_Intersection(a.track, b.track),
    a.imei
FROM
    tracks as a,
    tracks as b
WHERE
    st_intersects(a.track, b.track)
    AND a.imei!=b.imei
)
```

**CODE UPDATE 2:** The intersections cte above was not giving me the total number of intersections, so I tried the following:

```
intersections as

(SELECT ST_NumGeometries(ST_Collect(st_intersection(l1.track, l2.track))),l1.imei
FROM tracks AS l1
JOIN tracks AS l2 ON st_intersects(l1.track, l2.track)
where l1.imei != l2.imei 
GROUP BY st_intersection(l1.track, l2.track), l1.imei)
```

Now I am getting 1 in front of each imei, I guess I should add a buffer.

**CODE UPDATE 3:**  I have changed the last cte. Now am using ST_DWithin to provide me the 500m buffer.

```
intersections as 

(SELECT ST_NumGeometries(ST_Collect(st_intersection(l1.track, l2.track))),l1.imei
FROM tracks AS l1
JOIN tracks AS l2 ON ST_DWithin(l1.track::geography, 
l2.track::geography, 500)
where l1.imei != l2.imei 
GROUP BY st_intersection(l1.track, l2.track), l1.imei)
```

I am faced with the following error now:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: lwgeom_distance_spheroid returned negative!
```

So I have the individual components, but do not know how to piece it all together.

Here is a diagram to explain - [image]

Basically I want to see the total number of intersections between tracks, marked as stars, with the caveat that if tracks are within 5 m of each other, that is considered an intersection. (if this 5 m caveat is not possible, then I can just consider actual intersections without this "buffer" requirement)

Comment: added the screenshot, can you please help? thanks

Comment: Do you have the centroids as a table?

Comment: yes, it is in the "cluster_centroids_details" cte as shown above, thanks

Comment: Hey if you're trying to use meters you need to cast to geography.  Srid 4326 uses units of degrees so you'd be searching within 500 degrees (more than the entire earth)

Comment: Thanks, you mean like this? -  ON ST_DWithin(l1.track::geography, 
    l2.track::geography, 500)

Comment: when I converted, and ran the code, I got this error - SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: lwgeom_distance_spheroid returned negative!

Comment: This might be a trajectory question: are you trying to find when the objects that made the tracks are within 5m of each other (at a specific time) or just whether the tracks are close together, regardless of when the object was there. If it's the first option then you should look at the trajectory functions in PostGIS. They take time into consideration as a dimension for distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want buffered intersection, one simple way is to buffer your tracks before the intersection finding. I would go with something like this (buffer of 2.5m to have intersection with lines at 5m):

```
WITH tracks AS (
    SELECT 
        imei,
        ST_Buffer(ST_MakeLine(points_geom ORDER BY time_created)::geography, 2.5) AS track_buffered
    FROM dataset  
    GROUP BY imei
), intersections AS (
    SELECT
        ST_Centroid((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.track, b.track))).geom) as intersection,
        a.imei as first_track,
        b.imei as second_track,
    FROM
        tracks as a,
        tracks as b
    WHERE
        st_intersects(a.track, b.track)
        AND a.imei < b.imei;
)
SELECT * FROM intersections;
```

Note that I put `a.imei < b.imei` to not duplicate the intersections, and that as there can be multiple intersections between 2 tracks I dump the geom. Intersections are made from the centroïd of the intersection polygons, but there is other options like `ST_PointOnSurface`. Also, if you have 3 tracks that have one common intersection, you will have 2 intersections (maybe there is a post-treatment to do if you want to collide them). Also, for performance you should first create a table with your tracks and create index on it, otherwise it can be quite long if you have a lot of tracks.

Comment: I have made progress on this question, and moved it to an updated question - https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/441675/211549 . Can you please help with this? I have tried everything.