# Extract total length all linestrings within a certain radius of a point_geom column (not fixed point)

Tags: postgis

I have the total intersecting tracks given by the following code:

```
intersections_cte as(      
        select imei, intimei, st_length(st_union(intgeom)::geography) intlength,  st_union(intgeom) as intersecting_track
        from
        (
        select a.imei, b.imei intimei, 
            (st_dump(st_intersection(a.geom,b.track))).geom intgeom 
          from
          bufferedtracks a,
          tracks b
          where a.imei != b.imei and st_intersects(a.geom,b.track)
        ) allints
        group by imei, intimei;
       ) 
   
select * from intersections_cte
```

*please note -  "st_union(intgeom) as intersecting_track" gives a Multi-Linestring*

I also have a cluster_centroids_cte with distinct clusters in the format:

```
Cluster_id               Cluster_centroid_geom(SRID 4326)
```

**For each distinct cluster, I want to find the total lengths of all the intersecting tracks within 500m of that cluster centroid.**

I am having trouble as to how to proceed, here is the pseudocode of what I might think would work:

```
cluster_centroids_cte
cross join lateral
(intersection_cte
 where max distance between centroid and intersecting track < 500m
 )
```

**CODE UPDATE:**

I have implemented a cross join lateral as follows:

```
SELECT ccd.cluster_id,
       ccd.cluster_centroid,
       sum(routes.dist) 
from cluster_centroids_details  as ccd

CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT ST_DWITHIN(routes.intersecting_track::geography ,ccd.cluster_centroid::geography,500)  AS dist   
  FROM intersections_cte as routes
  ORDER BY dist
  
) routes;
group by 1,2
```

but am faced with the error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function sum(boolean) does not exist
```

**CODE UPDATE 2:** Replaced the cross join lateral with the code below. I know this is a step in the right direction, but I am not getting results for individual clusters, instead all results are combined. Should I go back to cross join lateral?

```
centroid_buffer as (
   select st_setsrid(st_buffer(ccd.cluster_centroid::geography,500)::geometry,4326) as buff_geom from 
     cluster_centroids_details ccd  
            )  

select  
   intlength as full_length,   
   st_length(
     ST_INTERSECTION(
        routes.intersecting_track,
        centroid_buffer.buff_geom 
      )
   ) as radius_bounded_length
from intersections_cte routes 
    INNER JOIN centroid_buffer 
        ON ST_DWITHIN(
          routes.intersecting_track::geography,
          centroid_buffer.buff_geom::geography,
          500)
```

**CODE UPDATE 3:** I am now doing the cross join lateral as shown below, which makes sense, but the values for the end sum of lengths per cluster are too low to be plausible.

```
SELECT ccd.cluster_id,
       ccd.cluster_centroid,
       sum(routes.tracks_within_radius)  
from cluster_centroids_details  as ccd

CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  
select  
   intlength as full_length,   
   st_length(
     ST_INTERSECTION(
        routes.intersecting_track,
        st_setsrid(st_buffer(ccd.cluster_centroid::geography,500)::geometry,4326) 
      )
   ) as tracks_within_radius
  from intersections_cte as routes
  where
    ST_DWITHIN(
      routes.intersecting_track::geography,
      ccd.cluster_centroid::geography,500) 
  
) routes
group by 1,2
```

Comment: you want `intersection` not `intersects`

Comment: in the cross join lateral query ?

Comment: sorry - reread on a bigger screen `ST_DWITHIN` is wrong as it returns a `boolean` not a line string - that is where you need an `st_intersection` with the `st_dwithin` as a where clause to filter them

Comment: I have just updated my code attempt to reflect this, but am not sure of the results, please help!

Comment: I have updated yet again, the code looks okay to me, but the final sum lengths are too low to be plausible.

Comment: Can someone please help? I do not know what else I can do.

Comment: I don't get what you want. For each cluster, you want the total length of the tracks that have an intersection within 500m ? Meaning if 2 tracks intersects within 500m, you want length_1 + length_2 ? Or length_1_within_500m + length_2_within_500m (which you seems to try to do) ? Or you also want to select for example tracks 3 and 4  that pass within 500m of your cluster but intersects  each other for example at 600m ? Also, in your last request, ST_INTERSECTION is between 2 polygons so the result should be a polygon too and the ST_Length does not make sense...

Comment: I want that common portion of line A and line B that is shared between the two geometries WITHIN 500m of centroid cluster. I want to sum up the length of all such common portions.

Comment: I think I have managed to do that here - https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/441705/211549

Comment: However I have to think about your comment - "Also, in your last request, ST_INTERSECTION is between 2 polygons so the result should be a polygon too and the ST_Length does not make sense... ". So you are saying the length is misleading?

Comment: I am not doing intersection between two polygons by the way, I am doing between a "multi-linestring" and a polygon (point buffered by 500m)