# Cross join lateral for radius bounded Multi-linestrings

Tags: postgis

Within a 500m radius of each centroid, I am trying to find out the total length of all multi-linestrings.

Am I doing this correctly? The values for the final sum are too low to be plausible.

*Please note "intersecting_track" is a Multi-Linestring with EPSG 4326*

Here is my code:

```
SELECT ccd.cluster_id,
       ccd.cluster_centroid,
       sum(routes.tracks_within_radius)  
from cluster_centroids_details  as ccd

CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  
select  
   intlength as full_length,   
   st_length(
     ST_INTERSECTION(
        routes.intersecting_track,
        st_setsrid(st_buffer(ccd.cluster_centroid::geography,500)::geometry,4326) 
      )
   ) as tracks_within_radius
  from intersections_cte as routes
  where
    ST_DWITHIN(
      routes.intersecting_track::geography,
      ccd.cluster_centroid::geography,500) 
  
) routes
group by 1,2
```

Comment: keep the intersection as `geography`, so its length will be in meters. As it is it, the length is in degree

Comment: thank you, that fixes things!